# Using Amazon EMR on a centralized host

Tags: json, hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I am trying to use Amazon EMR to process logs using the documentation here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-process-logs.html . I have created a PEM file and my credentials.json file and am able to successfully run and download the logs from S3 and create hive tabels on top of it and run map reduce queries.

Now I want to put all these credentials.json , PEM files and my script into a centralized host so that other users can come and just run the script and download the logs. No need for them to be creating their own key pair etc . So I just did a scp of the PEM files, script and the credential.json on the remote host and gave a permission of 777 on all of these. The problem is that when other users are running the script, they get an error "AWS credential not specified" .

Can anyone help me on this specific use case. Where are my credential setting going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For PEM files permission should be 600 .

Have you copied or created AwsCredentials.properties which have accessKey and secretKey ?

Or you need to add access key and secrete key in your path ( depends on how your script expects them.